# Received blank notification periodically in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, push, android-notifications

I have encountered with a  very strange issue in my App with Push Notification.
From last couple of weeks, i am getting the blank notification on my App. I am able to received push notification correctly related to order, campaign, promotional message from the application.

when i tried to found related to this in logcat, i got below logs. Tried to get the some solution using googling, but did not found any concrete reason for this.

Anyone have any ideas on this  ?

Logcat ::

```
2023-06-16 15:28:24.185  2606-2606  NotificationService     pid-2606                             E  Muting recently noisy 0|0|FCM-Notification:253925648|11704
2023-06-16 15:28:24.228  2606-2606  NotificationService     pid-2606                             E  Muting recently noisy 0|0|FCM-Notification:253925696|11704
2023-06-16 15:28:24.291  2606-2606  NotificationService     pid-2606                             E  Muting recently noisy 0|0|FCM-Notification:253925746|11704
2023-06-16 15:28:24.322  2606-2606  NotificationService     pid-2606                             E  Muting recently noisy 0|0|FCM-Notification:253925788|11704
```

Answer (score 1):

Android system is `muting notifications` from your app because it has been classified as *“recently noisy"* . Your app has sent a large number of notifications in a short period of time,

use features such as `notification channels` and `importance levels` to give users more control over the types of notifications they receive from your app to ensure that you are not sending too many notifications in a short period of time

From the app design end one or more of these maybe relevant to you :

- App code and logic :
  Look for changes to the logic that triggers notifications or changes to the data that is used to determine when notifications should be sent.
- Check for changes to `external data sources`  that triagger notification
- check how users are interacting with your app to see if there have been any changes in user behavior
- add `debugging statements` to your app’s code to log information about notifications:

  ```
  // Create a notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    // Add a debugging statement to log information about the notification
    Log.d("MyApp", "Sending notification: " + builder.toString());

    // Send the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
  ```

create a `NotificationCompat.Builder object` to build a `notification` and then use the `Log.d` method to log information about the notification. The `Log.d method` writes a message to the `logcat` with the `DEBUG log level`. You can use different log levels (e.g., `VERBOSE, INFO, WARN, ERROR`) to control the verbosity of your debugging statements.